# Prove that $(S \cap T)^c=S^c \cup T^c$ and $(S \cup T)^c=S^c \cap T^c$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that $(S \cap T)^c=S^c \cup T^c$ and $(S \cup T)^c=S^c \cap T^c$

$$(S \cap T)^c=S^c \cup T^c$$
$$(S \cap T)^c= (R \setminus S) \cup (R \setminus T)$$
$$(S \cap T)^c= R \setminus (S  \cup T)$$

I am new to this. I tried to go in this direction, but not very convinced.

What would an efficient way to prove those? thx for the input.

Comment: Tried https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=de+morgan+proof?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go back to the definition of $S\cap T$.

$S\cap T = \{ x\in R, x\in S \text{ and } x\in T\}$

This means for an element $x\in R$ to be in $S\cap T$, it has to be both in $S$ and $T$.

Now, by definition, $(S\cap T)^c = R \setminus S\cap T$.

Which is, for an element $x\in R$ to be in $(S\cap T)^c$ it has to verify $x\notin S\cap T$.

Put to words, $x\notin S\cap T$ means x is either out of $S$ or $T$ or both, which we can write as $x\in S^c\cup T^c$.

As for the formal demonstration, I honestly think this is something you have to deeply understand using what I just wrote or maybe using a De Venn diagram rather than a list of equations. As @Hans Lundmark pointed out, this is what we call the De Morgan rule and it is a key low level concept in logic.

Hope this helped, feel free to ask if I missed something.